# Installing a GnuPG tools stack using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, gnupg

To perform a software development task, I need to be sure I have a clean GnuPG Tools stack installed using Homebrew, but I seem to have accumulated some packages that look redundant. How do I install a full GnuPG Tools stack using Homebrew, without ending up with redundant (and possibly conflicting) packages?

I currently have the following installed

- gnupg
- gnupg2
- gpg-agent
- gpgtools (as a cask)

Do I need all of these? Can I prune or remove some of them?

Comment: Your question does not seem specific to software development at all to me. Consider asking on Super User or Ask Different instead.

Comment: @JensErat: It's a typical SO question (just look at the "related" or click on the [homebrew tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew)). Super User? Ask Different? Neither of those will produce a useful answer (esp. not Ask Different). Have the SO policies changed? You're WAY off base.

Comment: I don't see how installing general usage software packages is specific to software development at all. There might be some overlap with homebrew question being very well on-topic on Stack Overflow (developing packages, packages _specific_ for software development, ...), but I wouldn't consider this one to be among them. Stack Overflow has a vast close vote queue and lots of off topic questions never make it through the queue, which does not make all those questions a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JensErat: I don't know where you came from (or why you're committed to being unhelpful), but this is a typical question for this form. See other questions in the related sidebar (none closed or viewed as off topic, some very highly rated with great useful answers).

Comment: I'm monitoring the [tag:gnupg] tag where I'm answering _lots_ of questions. But I won't to do so if they're off topic on the page I'm on. I did do so earlier days and proposed migrations, but since questions continued being closed without migrations on Stack Overflow I completely stopped doing so. Most people providing quality answers will be monitoring tags, by the way, and again most will do so network-wide, so you'll attract the same people anyway. Have a look at the [FAQ] to read through the topic list for Stack Overflow, "what packages to install to use crypto software" is not among them.

Comment: @JensErat: That's some of the most robotic "reasoning" I've ever seen. What? I've edited the question to help you along.